# UI for creating business rules in NRules

Tags: .net, rule-engine, codeeffects, nrules

I have been searching for a rules engine to be used in a data import system i am creating.

I found several rules engines but it looks like NRules is the most popular also i found CodeEffects which is good but not free.

So i was wondering if there is a friendly UI to let the end-users create the rules with NRules just like CodeEffects [demo](http://codeeffects.com/Business-Rule-Demo).

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you use the mvc version? i want to use it in an angular 4 app, any thoughts?

Comment: There is a good reason why CodeEffects isn't free - the code to write the UI was probably orders of magnitude more difficult than writing the business rules engine itself.